# "Say what you see" is a way of transforming a string of digits based on its spoken transcription in python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the problem: "Say what you see" is a way of transforming a string of digits based on its spoken transcription in python

**Explanation:**

```
1 --> "one 1" --> 11
21 --> "one 2, one 1" --> 1211
321 --> "one 3, one 2, one 1" --> 131211
```

this problem is based on `Say what you see`

Input:
`["12","21"]`

Expected Output:

`1112`
`1211`

Can anyone please suggest something?

Comment: Can you explain how you get these outputs from that input? It is not clear to me

Comment: @Tomerikoo There are one 1, and one 2; therefore, [1 1 1 2]

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks. And now, did you try anything already? we will be glad to help you with a bump in your code

Comment: @Tomerikoo, We can say `12: one 1, one 2 --> 1112`

Comment: Why are there two expected outputs for the input ["12","21"]? What is the rule to get the output(s) from a general input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without using any package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def say_what_you_see(s):
    rs = []  # 233 --> [[1, '2'], [2, '3']]
    for i in s:
        if not rs or rs[-1][1] != i:
            rs.append([1, i])
        else:
            rs[-1][0] += 1
    return "".join("{}{}".format(*i) for i in rs)


def main():
    while True:
        a = input("Number: ")
        if a == "q":
            break
        print("Result:", say_what_you_see(a))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the same digits and then create a new number based on the number of occurrence of the digit and the actual digit

```
>>> n = 321
>>> ''.join(i for k,grp in groupby(str(n)) for i in (str(len(list(grp))), k))
'131211'

>>> n = 3221
>>> ''.join(i for k,grp in groupby(str(n)) for i in (str(len(list(grp))), k))
'132211'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `re`:

```
import re

s = ["12","21", "321"]

for i in s:
    print(''.join('{}{}'.format(len(m[0]), m[1]) for m in re.findall(r'((.)\2*)', i)))
```

Prints:

```
1112
1211
131211
```

Comment: Can we do that without using any package?

Comment: @Vish well you have the other answer, but `re` is standard library so no special reason not to use it...

Comment: No special reason, just want to learn